# RS485 ground noise problem

Tags: noise, ground, rs485

I'm using the USB FTDI [dongle](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_USB_RS485_CABLES.pdf) to convert USB to RS485, half duplex, 3 wires (A+, B-, GND) with 115200 baud rate.

I'm working with controller of NXP (K64) and I'm experiencing random tx enables on the input signal of the MX3362 (half duplex RS485 to UART). the tx enable is caused due to noise (?) coming from the outside into the inputs of the max3362 (I think).

When I disconnected the GND wire, the problem disappeared. When I'v lowered down the baud rate to 9600, also, the problem disappeared, so I'm guessing it is concerned with noisy ground.

Some board I've tested act the same, but others still have issue, nevertheless, when lowering down the baudrate, it seems those phenomenas has decreased but not vanished (in those boards). 
Any ideas how to overcome that issue?

Attached my electrical scheme:

[image]

Comment: which gnd, and where you disconnected it?

Comment: gnd wire in the communication cable of the USB FTDI dongle (connecting to pin 8 in the connector in the scheme)

Comment: Is your computer ground the same as the K64 board ground? Can you measure the voltage between the two grounds?

Comment: Have you got terminating resistors on both ends of the bus (120R)? Even at slow speeds, these matter. Also make sure that the pull up/down resistors are sized correctly (500R). Too high and you will get noise. Too low and there isn't enough drive on the transceivers.

Comment: Which pull up/down resistors?    I have 2 serial termination resistors of 165 ohm, but they are a mistake, and even when taking them out, still I have toggling on my tx_ena line.